# Python Test value of indexed character in string

Tags: python

I have the below code (this is the full source):

```
testString = 'hello'
one = testString[0]
print one
if one == 'h'
    print "all is good"
else
    print "an error was encountered"
raw_input()
```

The error I'm getting here is as follows:
"file "", line 1
if one == 'h'
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What I want to do is then run the variable 'one' through a test to ascertain it's value i.e. if one = a run functionA, elif one = b etc.  The problem I am encountering is that I simply can't run such a test (i.e. one = a) for some reason - the console just opens and closes straight away suggesting an error.  How can I test the value of this variable (which I think may not be a string) against strings?

I'm writing this in Notepad++ and running the .py

EDIT:
I've tried running it in the console and I get the below error:
[image: errors encountered]

Comment: are you using `==` rather than `=`?

Comment: What do you mean the console opens and closes right away?  Are you trying to launch the program from a GUI environment?  This won't happen if you run python from the commandline, I wouldn't think.  What the whole script look like?

Comment: To get an idea of what's going on, open your console first, and then type `python yourfile.py` to see what is the actual error.

Comment: @sfletche I'm using 'if one = h' etc, not '=='

Comment: @RayToal I'm running the .py file (as in going into Win Explorer and double clicking the .py file).  This is the whole script that I've included

Comment: '=' is assignment; use '==' to make a comparation.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I've done that and included an image of the problem I'm encountering.  The advice to change to '==' may have resolved the issue, but still not working

Comment: @RayToal I find double clicking the .py works fine for me, although as you rightly point out I don't get any errors when I do that.  I probably should change that bad habit of mine ;)

Comment: You might want to go through a tutorial as this is a basic issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the image you posted, the error you received is Invalid Syntax on the line

```
if one == 'h' print 'good'
```

It should have been

```
if one == 'h':
    print 'good'
```

You need a colon, and indentation matters.

**ASIDE**

By the way, it *is* permissable in Python to write this on one line, but the colon is required.

```
if one == 'h': print 'good'
```

but really, this one line version is very rare and not at all recommended.

Comment: thanks for that - thought I'd made a rookie mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you are trying to do:

```
testString = 'hello'
one = testString[0]
two = testString[1]
three = testString[2]
four = testString[3]
five = testString[4]
pi = 3.14159

def isH():
    print "Letter is h"

def isE():
    print "Letter is e"

def isL():
    print "Letter is l"

def isO():
    print "Letter is o"

def test(myVar):
    if myVar == 'h' or myVar == 'H':
        isH()
    elif myVar == 'e' or myVar == 'E':
        isE()
    elif myVar == 'l' or myVar == 'L':
        isL()
    elif myVar == 'o' or myVar == 'O':
        isO()
    else:
        print "Unrecognized variable" 


test(one)
test(two)
test(three)
test(four)
test(five)
test(pi)
```

Running the above code produces:

```
Letter is h
Letter is e
Letter is l
Letter is l
Letter is o
Unrecognized variable
```

The beauty of Python is that variables of different types can often be compared against each other.

For example:

```
x == '2' # Returns False
[1, 2, 3] == (1, 2, 3) # Returns False
```

As suggested by Tolli, you could store the functions in a dictionary to help simplify your code.

Comment: You could also convert the letter to lower case, so you don't have to check both upper and lower case. For example, `if myVar.lower() == 'h': isH()`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this (all you were missing was a colon):

```
if one == "h": print "one is good."
```

If you have a bunch of functions for different values of one, you may wish to use a lookup table like this:

```
# A table of functions to be called depending on the value of `one`
functions = {
    'a': functionA,
    'b': functionB,
    # etc.
}

# lookup the function for one in the table, 
# or set function to None is a matching function is not found.
function = functions.get(one, None)
if function is not None:
    # call the desired function
    function()
else:
    # There is no function for the value of one
    # Handle this case in some way (maybe raise an exception)
```

Comment: You said " if one = a run functionA, elif one = b etc.". That is what this code does.

Comment: Ah I see now and remove my previous comment.  I understand now sorry!